# How to parse Json with Array list

Tags: json, parsing, response

I have below response from an API get call.
How do i read the value of dummyId and testcontactId. Below is the sample response:

```
{
   "pageCount":1,
   "pageIndex":0,
   "pageSize":200,
   "totalCount":1,
   "dto":{
"data":[
     {
            "callDuration":"0:00:07",
            "dummyId":20,
            "testcontactId":"3002",
            "id":54
         }
      ],
      "columns":[
         {
            "fieldName":"test1",
            "displayName":"test Id",
            "show":true,
            "sortable":true,
            "fieldType":"string",
            "order":1
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't place a comment to ask what language you're using, Here is how you'd do it in **JavaScript**

Parse your API Result to a Object with `var data = JSON.parse()` [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Then you can just go `data.dto.data[0].dummyId`
Since `dto.data` is an array, You can just use the indexes to access each option.
if you need to find specific values, You might want to take a look at [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

*In the future, Please add a tag with your programming language and things you've tried.*